# How can I get an OpenGL Error String in LWJGL 3?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to debug a small program that uses LWJGL 3.1.5, but I can't for the life of me find the LWJGL3 equivalent of methods like `glewGetErrorString` that return an OpenGL error. It appears that LWJGL2 had `translateGLErrorString` ([old javadoc](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Util.html)), but I've been searching for quite a while and can't find an LWJGL3 equivalent.

Comment: Does this from the LWJGL forum help? http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5745.0 (read the whole thread)

Comment: @JimGarrison I saw it earlier and it didn't look relevant, so I skipped past it, but it looks like the bit about `GLUtil.setupDefaultMessageCallback();` solved my problem, even more conveniently than I was expecting.